# Integration wrt BM

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

How do I integrate:
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} (S_t - K)^+ \phi(t) dt$ where $\phi$ is a normal density and $S_t$ is a geometric brownian motion?

I know my answer should be $\Phi(d_1)$, where $\Phi$ is the normal CDF and $d_1$ is the $d_1$ appearing in the [Black-Scholes price of a European option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Black-Scholes_formula).

Comment: What is $K $? ${}{} $

Comment: @Ian $K$ is the strike price.

Comment: Exactly, so just some $K\geq 0$.

Comment: Do you know what the solution for the stock price following a geometric Brownian motion? and knowing what the form of the normal distribution can you compute the integral/

Comment: Yes it is $S_0e^{((r-\sigma^2/2)t + \sigma W_t)}$but I was thrown a bit off by the $-^+$ constraint.

Comment: I'm assuming its supposed to be like the Laplace transform of a standard normal, times some constants...

Comment: you have an lower bound based off the fact that $S_T > K$ ps check that your expectation should be $\mathbb{E}\left[(S_T-K)^+\right]$ and not $S_t$>